# ACF Field to give specific discount to woocommerce Customer

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create something wonder if anyone had any ideas on how I would do it. I'm trying to build a 'Discount per customer' system into my website where the admin can enter a value (Say 20) into an Advanced Custom Field on the edit user (backend) screen which gets saved to the user meta.

This value is then used to give a discount on the total price of their cart. e.g. if you put 20% then the customer would always get 20% off on their items. Think of it as a loyalty system.

Would love to hear everyones ideas

Comment: It doesn't directly answer your question, but you might want to look at  WC's built in support for coupons; you can create coupons that apply a % discount off the entire cart AND specify which email addresses they apply to. The customer still has to enter the code in but that might actually reinforce the notion that they are *receiving* the discount.

Comment: Cheers @Dre, I'm aware of this feature, just wanted to eliminate a loyal customers need to enter a coupon

Comment: I've done a bit of digging; [WC provides a `woocommerce_calculate_totals` hook and a `woocommerce_calculated_totals` filter](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#1355-1361) that you can use. Looks like the hook passes the whole cart object, so you can probably do something like `$cart->discount_total = $your_calculated_discount`

Comment: Do you know how i'd set the value

 `code function mysite_box_discount( $cart ) {
  
    global $woocommerce;
 
 /* Get Value of Discount */
 $discount_value = get_field('customer_discount', $user_id);
 
 /* Set it as a percentage */
 
 
   
      // Alter the cart discount total
      $cart->discount_total = $total_discount;
    }   
}
add_action('woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'mysite_box_discount');  `code`